# i want to make a checkbox to edit slected files for a mutilple file upload input field , before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function direct() 
          {
           var x= document.getElementById('fileupload-example-4').value ;
           var String=x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("\'")+1,x.lastIndexOf("."));
           alert(x);
           alert(String);
           document.getElementById('filedirect').value=String;

          }
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" id="filedirect" readonly style="width:260px; height:30px;border:0px;">
           <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
           <input type="file" id="fileupload-example-4" onchange="direct()"  multiple> <label id="fileupload-example-4-label" for="fileupload-example-4">ADD</label></div>
```

i am making a multiple file upload input field for a form. I want to make a checkbox that will allow user to deselect or add more files. how to make such a file upload input field

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: sorry, my bad , what i did was , basic.so, thought wouldnt be helpful, i am adding it now.

Comment: now the problem , is even if i select two boxes , only one file is shown in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write it yourself, you can use a plugin such as:

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/